# PowerShellのインストールは必要？＋なぜnameがdefineされない？

Tags: python, powershell, anaconda3

プログラミング初心者です。

ワークショップに参加し、”results”という名前をつけたリストを使うことになりました。講師からグーグルコラボラトリでリストが共有されたので、まず初めに、そのリストをVSCodeにコピペしたのが画像です。
あれこれ試す前にとりあえずリストをprintしようとしたら、下記の説明が。

①Install the latest PowerShell for new features and improvements! https://aka.ms/PSWindows
②NameError: name 'results' is not defined

①について
powershellのインストールは必要なのでしょうか。必要ならしますが、実行結果の表示も後に出ては来るので、さほど重要でないのに求められているような気もします。インストールの仕方を解説したHPはありましたが、必要性についてきちんと解説しているものが見当たりませんでした。毎回出現されると邪魔な文言なので、どなたか教えてくれるとありがたいです。

②について
JupyterNotebookにコピペしたら普通に実行できるのに、VSCodeだと認識してくれません。なぜでしょうか。Nameerrorとのことですが、エラーの原因がわかりません。

Windows11でANACONDAをインストールし、VSCodeとJupyterNotebookを使っています。今月インストールしたのでどれも最新です。VSCodeではPythonのバージョンは3.9.12と表示されています。こちらもよろしくお願いします。[image: リストをコピペしてプリントしようとした状態]

Comment: このファイルは何というファイル名で保存しましたか?

Comment: practiceというファイル名で保存しました

Comment: practice.ps のような拡張子にしたんじゃないかと思ったんですが、そうではないのですね。

Answer (score 0):

VSCodeにPython用の拡張機能インストールや環境設定が行われていないか、新しいファイルを作成・保存した時に対象言語がPythonになっていないと思われます。

①はPythonとは独立した内容であり無関係です。必要不要の区別は今回の件とは別に貴方が他の関連することややりたいことの条件等を基に決めてください。
ちなみに最新版に更新してもデフォルトだと著作権表示と何らかのメッセージは表示されます。
現在(あるいは最新)の版数でも起動時のオプションに`-NoLogo`を指定すれば非表示になります。
[about_PowerShell_exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe?view=powershell-5.1)

②は①も含めて、対象ファイルがPythonではなくPowerShellとか何か別の言語のスクリプトとして設定・認識されているために発生している可能性が高いでしょう。

**--追記：②に関して--**
もしかしたら、以下の記事にある「ターミナルでカーソル行を実行」を行っているのかもしれません。

[ターミナルでカーソル行を実行](https://www.python.jp/python_vscode/windows/run/exec_in_terminal.html#%E3%82%BF%E3%83%BC%E3%83%9F%E3%83%8A%E3%83%AB%E3%81%A7%E3%82%AB%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BD%E3%83%AB%E8%A1%8C%E3%82%92%E5%AE%9F%E8%A1%8C)

1行目からの`results = [[...]]`を実行せず、`print(results)`の行だけを`Shift`+`Enter`キーで実行しているということはありませんか？
その場合はresultsが定義されていないので質問のようなエラーが発生する可能性が考えられます。

上記記事のその上にある[ターミナルで選択範囲を実行](https://www.python.jp/python_vscode/windows/run/exec_in_terminal.html#%E3%82%BF%E3%83%BC%E3%83%9F%E3%83%8A%E3%83%AB%E3%81%A7%E9%81%B8%E6%8A%9E%E7%AF%84%E5%9B%B2%E3%82%92%E5%AE%9F%E8%A1%8C)を参考に全てを選択して`Shift`+`Enter`キーで実行するか、編集内容を拡張子`.py`のテキストファイルに保存して[ターミナルでPythonを実行](https://www.python.jp/python_vscode/windows/run/exec_in_terminal.html#%E3%82%BF%E3%83%BC%E3%83%9F%E3%83%8A%E3%83%AB%E3%81%A7Python%E3%82%92%E5%AE%9F%E8%A1%8C)で実行してみてください。
**--追記終了--**

こちらの記事などを参考に、それらが行われているかを確認し、不足していれば作業を行ってください。
分からない・知らない単語や内容があるなら、Webで検索してみると良いでしょう。
他にも色々な情報がWeb上にあります。

[Visual Studio Code を Python 用に設定する方法](https://python.softmoco.com/devenv/how-to-setup-vs-code-for-python.php)
[【VSCode】ファイルの種類や設定を変更・確認する方法｜拡張子・インデントなど](https://blog-and-destroy.com/30994)
[新しいファイルを作成する/ファイルを保存する](https://www.javadrive.jp/vscode/file/index6.html)

---

例えばWindows PowerShellのコマンドプロンプトで質問内容を短縮して直接試してみると以下のようになります。これはWindows10のPowerShell 5.1でのものですが、質問の①の内容が以下の「新しいクロスプラットフォーム...」の行に相当するでしょう。質問の表示はおそらくPowerShell の6系～7系のうち最新でないものが使われているためだと思われます。

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

新しいクロスプラットフォームの PowerShell をお試しください https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS C:\Users\UserName> results = [['Calabria', 50.8],
>> ['Sardinia', 53.17]]
results : 用語 'results' は、コマンドレット、関数、スクリプト ファイル、または操作可能なプログラムの名前として認識され
ません。名前が正しく記述されていることを確認し、パスが含まれている場合はそのパスが正しいことを確認してから、再試行して
ください。
発生場所 行:1 文字:1
+ results = [['Calabria', 50.8],
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (results:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

PS C:\Users\UserName>
```